# Angular Date Functions

Tags: angularjs, date, datetime

I am new to Angular and am having trouble doing simple date functions.

```
$scope.publishDate = new Date().setHours(0);
```

This works but these do not

```
$scope.publishDate = new Date().setMinutes(0);
$scope.publishDate = new Date().addDays(0);
```

Do I need add additional libraries like angular-moment or geomoment to have these extra date functions?

Comment: Use moment.js and save yourself all the pain :)

Comment: What happens you try those functions? For example, `addDays()` doesn't seem to be part of the Date API (per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)). I would expect an error if you tried to call `addDays()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently created a wrapper for use moment inside angular,

https://github.com/jcamelis/angular-moment

You can use all moment methods as angular filters.

Answer (score 0):

Those are native functions and depends on each browser to implement the ECMA Script standard that applies. The good news is that those features should be present in all browser these days.

Here is a link if you want to learn more about the standard and the version and browsers that supports it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours

Answer (score 0):

Dates can be awkward in Javascript, especially if you're new to them.

I've been using moment on an angular project recently and would totally recommend it, though you don't need it.

It makes getting, setting and formatting dates incredibly easy. :)